# loading javascript into an iframe

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, iframe

So I was having an issue with an "undefined variable" in Internet Explorer.

Specifically -
The undefined variable is a global Javascript var within the JSP where I have an iFRAME. The reason that I deduced that this var it is NOT DEFINED is because the JS code where I instantiate it is NOT getting loaded into the iframe. I tried putting the JS Code directly within my JSP page which constructs a table within my iFrame, but it never gets loaded in IE or Safari.  FF loads this JS code though...

I tried putting my JS code into a tag and then calling that tag library from within my iframe - but still NOTHING. While I am degubbing I try to put a breakpoint next to the line of code where I instatiate this object - I get the error message within IE8 debugger - "Cannot add breakpoint in this location. The code for this page has not been loaded."

Here is my iframe that I call from the parent -

```
    <iframe src="${channelUrl}" onload='<c:if test="${ConfigProperties.test.mode ne 'true'}">setIframeAnchor("iframeportlet")</c:if>' name="iframeportlet" id="iframeportlet" style="height: ${frameHeight}px; width: 100%" title="E-Doc" frameborder="0" height="${frameHeight}px" scrolling="auto" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Question -

How and where do I place my JS code in the parent window and/or within my iframe?

Comment: Post some `js` code or this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607398/force-iframe-to-evaluate-its-javascript/9608160#9608160) may give you an idea.

Comment: Is the iframe on your domain, or elsewhere? You can't touch the content of frames that aren't on your domain.

Comment: @duskwuff - Yes, same domain.