# Handling iFrame event in the parent web page

Tags: javascript, events, iframe, event-handling, dom-events

I have a question about communicating between a iFrame and parent or containing web page.

Can I trigger an event in iFrame and handle it in the parent containing web page containing it? The iFrame and the parent page belongs to same sub-domain.

Comment: If they are from the same subdomain, yes. The parent page and iframe should be able to interact.

Comment: [This may help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607398/force-iframe-to-evaluate-its-javascript/9608160#9608160).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the link Sheikh Heera provided in the comments, yes, you can trigger events in an iframe and handle it in the parent.

```
var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
doc.getElementById("myDiv").addEventListener('click',function() {
    //doStuffHere
});
```

Here's a fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/9sfm9/

---

OR just call `parent.doFunction()` in the iframe's JavaScript, assuming, `doFunction()` is a function in the parent page. Example:

parent script:

```
var doFunction = function() {
    alert("I was triggered from an iframe");
}
```

iframe script:

```
parent.doFunction();
```

And here's a fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/9sfm9/2/

Comment: Your jsfiddle does not work anymore in chrome.  Error is "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://fiddle.jshell.net" from accessing a frame with origin "null".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "data". Protocols must match."

Comment: Now it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')"`